# md3000i : recover data from healthy unplugged hard disk but with deleted configuration on the array

Tags: configuration, hard-drive, storage-area-network, dell-powervault

I have a question for an MD3000i SAN expert :

We had a RAID with 2 disks on a MD3000i DELL SAN. We deleted the configuration on the storage array without the disks of this RAID configuration plugged inside.

Now we put back the disks inside the array and we are trying to read the data on them.
Unfortunately, the array didn't recognized the disks.

Do you know how to reuse our disks and read again the data on the array (can we somehow retreive the configuration applied to the disks and recreate the proper configuration on the array) ?

This also makes me wonder what would happen if we had a hardware failure on the MD3000i and bought a new one. Would we be facing the same issue and not be able to use our disks and retrieve the data on them ?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: `what would happen if we had a hardware failure` - that's a question for the Dell support or for a documentation study.

Answer (score 2):

the SAN should detect a foreign logical disk (array), and provide the option to import it. If it doesn't detect a foreign config, you might have to re-tag. For the exact procedure, you need to talk to Dell techsupport